# One of two uvmaps is not showing image

Tags: materials, uv

I have defined 2 uvmaps on one object. I assigned different materials with the same color but different images. For some reason only one is showed up - why?

As you can see, the 1st UV works just fine:

[image]

But the other one on opposite site does not show up at all!

[image]

Here is my test file.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not plugged anything into the *Vector* input of the *Image Texture* node. Without any input, it uses the default UV map which is set to *Active Render*, in your case this is the one named "g1" (and it can always be only one single map be set to active).

[image: active uv map]

To use different UV maps for different textures, you can for example take a *UV Map* node, select the desired map there and plug it into the *Vector* input of the *Image Texture* node:

[image: uv map node]

Comment: Yes, that made the job nicely, BUT now it shows just red rectangle in the Preview panel in the material tab - why? Before it was showing the image with correct red bg (you can see it on the image in my question post).

Comment: @fafa Honestly I don't know how the material preview handles different UV maps and me personally never care much for those previews - as long as I have setup the materials correctly and they are working when I render my scene, that's the only thing important to me. I just made a test: I created a third UV map just with default unwrapping which has ALL faces unwrapped over the map. If I plug this in, the preview looks like before. I guess it has something to do with the preview not really being the actual object and having some kind of default UVs for showcasing, too. But I don't know.

Comment: No problem, to be clear it is not important for me as well but I just wanted to know what is going on with the preview. But I have another problem regarding exporting to Collada, gonna make new post - gee this Blender! ;-)